# why could my code be stopping at this point in my code?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My code runs until it reaches this section of code then it stops

```
      int i,y;
      short int** audiodata = (short int **)calloc(nsample*2, sizeof(short int*));
      for( i=0 ; i<nsample ; i++)
      {
        for( y=0 ; y<1 ; y++)   
        {
           audiodata[i][y]= (short int) (32700.0* sin(2*pi*freq*(float)i/44100) );
         }
      }
```

what errors am i not seeing and i have a printf statement after this section of code that let the user know it finished loading the 2-d array but the printf never get executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops"?  Do you get a runtime error?  Does the application become unresponsive?  How are you executing it (command line, IDE, something else)?

Comment: `for( y=0 ; y<1 ; y++)` you know this executes the loop just once, so you'll probably just need the body with `0` instead of `y`, right?

Comment: `audiodata[i][whatever]` is not allocated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did not allocate arrays of pointers of the type `short int *`. So this statement

```
audiodata[i][y]= (short int) (32700.0* sin(2*pi*freq*(float)i/44100) );
         ^^^^^^
```

has undefined bahavior.

What you mean is the following

```
  short int** audiodata = calloc( nsample, sizeof( short int* ) );

  for ( i = 0; i < nsample; i++ )
  {
       audiodata[i] = calloc( 2, sizeof( short int ) );
  }

  for ( i = 0; i < nsample; i++ )
  {
      for ( y = 0; y < 2; y++ )   
      {
          audiodata[i][y]= (short int) (32700.0* sin(2*pi*freq*(float)i/44100) );
      }
  }
```